# Python pandas: merge dataframe to series on series's index and dataframe's column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following series:

```
>>>counts = pd.Series({'0.0':5, '1.0':6, '2.0':14, '3.0':98})
>>>counts
0.0     5
1.0     6
2.0    14
3.0    98
dtype: int64
```

and dataframe:

```
>>>topic_keywords = [(0, 0.0, 'challenge, web, language, require, bot'),
                     (1, 3.0, 'time, huge, figure, image, run, develop'),
                     (2, 1.0, 'datum, user, access, speech, bandwidth'),
                     (3, 2.0, ' main, decide, audio, sensor, disabled, make'),
                     (4, 2.0, ' main, decide, audio, sensor, disabled, make'),
                     (5, 0.0, 'challenge, web, language, require, bot')]
>>> topicKeywordsDf = pd.DataFrame(topic_keywords, columns=['ID', 'Topic_Num', 'Topic_Keywords'])
>>> topicKeywordsDf = topicKeywordsDf.set_index('ID')
>>> topicKeywordsDf
    Topic_Num                                Topic_Keywords
ID
0         0.0        challenge, web, language, require, bot
1         3.0       time, huge, figure, image, run, develop
2         1.0        datum, user, access, speech, bandwidth
3         2.0   main, decide, audio, sensor, disabled, make
4         2.0   main, decide, audio, sensor, disabled, make
5         0.0        challenge, web, language, require, bot
```

I'd like to merge the dataframe on the series where the index of the Series would match with the `Topic_Num` column of the dataframe:

```
Topic_Num    Count    Topic_Keywords
0.0         5        challenge, web, language, require, bot
1.0         14       datum, user, access, speech, bandwidth
2.0         6        main, decide, audio, sensor, disabled, make
3.0         98       time, huge, figure, image, run, develop
```

Preferably, the final dataframe should be sorted based on `Topic_Num`. How do I merge these?

**Attempts:**

```
counts_df = counts.to_frame()
merge = counts_df.merge(topicKeywordsDf, left_index=True, right_on="Topic_Num")
```

But get this error:

> ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and float64 columns. If
>   you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Comment: Why is the index of `counts` strings representing floats instead of just floats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got to add a few things:

First, your counts_df has no column name, adding the name will get you a Dataframe with a column name

```
counts_df=pd.DataFrame({'Topic_Num':counts.index, 'value':counts.values})
```

Your merge now works. You should drop the columns you won't use and consider if you want duplicates. If your counts_df is sorted, your merge will be so.

```
merge = counts_df.merge(topicKeywordsDf, left_index=True, right_on="Topic_Num").drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: I tried that but got this error: `ValueError: You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat`

Comment: It works for me, but just to check, can you try counts = pd.Series({0.0:5, 1.0:6, 2.0:14, 3.0:98}) ?

Comment: no error now, but the results in not as expected, it has 6 rows (like the second dataframe) while it should have 4 rows as in the first dataframe.

Comment: merge = counts_df.merge(topicKeywordsDf, left_index=True, right_on="Topic_Num").drop_duplicates()